# Oauth2 resource server does not call jwk set uri

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, jwk

Problem is Oauth2 resource server I configured does not call the jwk-set-uri to validate tokens and always return 401- Unauthrized response. I have configured a Oauth2 Resource server with following,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

as only dependencies and

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/well-known/jwks

in application.yml file.

I am confused about why this setup doesn't work. Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: What Spring Security's configuration do you have?